# Get OP_RETURN from bitcoin-cli

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, op-return, command-line-options

Is there a way to extract old OP_RETURN transactions from the commandline with bitcoin-cli or something? 
Something in the way of getAllOpRetFromBlock(345345) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not quite the method you are looking for, but you can use the `getblock` call which takes the block hash (not height, you can get the hash of a specific height using `getblockhash` method). That will give you the block, and you would then need to write a script to iterate through the transactions in the block and find ones which have an OP_RETURN output.